# Camera for android - one picture from several

Tags: android, photography, camera

Can you recommend a camera application for Android, which gets several pictures in a series and them merges it to a single picture with less noise and better resolution?

Something like [this](https://www.playmemoriescameraapps.com/portal/usbdetail.php?eid=IS9104-NPIA09014_00-000002) application for Sony cameras ...

Comment: I'm not sure if the burst mode (or super mode) from [A Better Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.almalence.opencam) covers that, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Where can I read what burst mode in Better Camera is actually doing?

Comment: If I had found that I had been more precise. That's why I wrote to give it a try (and see).